# Faking max-device-width

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, browser, mobile-website

To implement mobile website it would be useful to set max-device-width in my browser.
I know plugins to fake the user-agent. It this also possible for the max-device-width?
I would prefer to use a regular browser like Firefox, IE, Opera, ... instead of all kind of mobile browser emulators or even different smartphones.

Thanks,
Ropo

Comment: relevant: http://www.jonhiggins.co.uk/words/max-device-width/

Answer (score 15):

Chrome allows you to set device metrics, which are used in the media queries calculation for device width. To do that, open Developer Tools, click the gear icon on the lower right corner, and go to the Overrides tab.

**Edit Jan. 17, 2014**: Chrome now has an Emulation tab, that can be found alongside Console, in Developer Tools.

Answer (score 5):

In the common case desktop browsers can be used for sanity checks of html & css, but mobile browsers are very different in the html, css and javascript processing.

To *"emulate"* `max-device-width` you can replace `max-device-width` with `max-width` and resize your browser window to required size (actual versions of browsers supports `max-width` media-query instruction).

We use desktop browsers at the early stages of mobile web interface development and emulators in late. UI testers use real devices only.

Comment: This did not actually work for me. I changed my user agent string in Firefox and made the browser extremely narrow, yet my site was still rendering with the full screen version on my laptop and with the max-device-width 480 on my iPhone.

Comment: Can you provide html & css what are you using?

Comment: Kevin is right, this won't work. max-width, which is probably what you're thinking about, Phillip, is separate from max-device-width. The only way I know to emulate this is to just change your code to use max-width, either temporarily or permanently, depending on the circumstances. It's not a perfect emulation, particularly with regards to device rotation, but it's usually good enough for most testing. Also, check out this bookmarklet: http://www.benjaminkeen.com/misc/bricss/

Comment: I'm sorry. I had `max-width` in mind, when answer was written. Yes, `max-device-width` can be replaced with `max-width` while resource debugging. I had fix the answer, thanks.