# How to simulate device-width and orientation in browser to test media queries?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, media-queries, device-width

I'm developing my website locally and using Chrome to preview it as I go. While it's really easy to resize the browser to test media queries that use `max/min-width`, it's not possible from what I can tell to simulate `max/min-device-width` with any built in settings. Is there a Chrome extension that will simulate a mobile device and trigger media queries, specifically `max/min-device-width` and also `orientation:portrait/landscape`?

I basically would like some way to test this media query with Chrome on my computer rather than a smartphone:
`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait)`

Comment: If you can't find it by googling it probably doesn't exist. I don't rely on browser resizing, best to test it on actual devices or join crossbrowsertesting.com and avoid the simulators, they have lots of devices. Also, there's http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ for just looking at various sizes.

Comment: I need a local solution. I don't want to tweak, upload, refresh, repeat. Otherwise I'd just use my physical devices. A Chrome extension would be perfect!

Comment: See [Faking max-device-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149131/faking-max-device-width). Answer from user _wasabi_ may help you if you are using Chrome.

Comment: @AntoJurković Thanks, but that unfortunately didn't do the trick. It did not render various UI elements at the correct size, including font and SVG files.

Comment: Mobile emulation is available in the Beta Channel http://blog.chromium.org/2013/12/chrome-devtools-for-mobile-emulate-and.html https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: Thanks @rsanchez! That improved emulator is working much better. Still not perfect. It still renders the font too large compared to what it actually looks like on a real iPhone, but this is good enough. :) Care to state that as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mobile device emulation is available as a [built-in feature](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) for Chrome, currently in the Beta channel. You need to enable it in the DevTools settings.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try...I think it's exactly what you need...
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsiview/kcemonjjmilbiepahkhanlkddonpjlep?hl=en-US

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried that extension before posting. The problem with this is that it doesn't simulate `device-width` - only regular `width`. Also, doesn't work at all for local files.

Comment: Seems to simulate device width for me. Not sure about local testing, I'm only using it with live examples.